# Kendo UI Mobile App not rendering like Android or iOS

Tags: android, ios, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I created a new project in Visual Studio which was a Telerik>AppBuilder>Drawer Application. The problem is that it doesn't look like android (not using the android stylesheet) when simulating android nor iOS (not using the iOS stylesheet) when simulating iOS. It is always just a plain gray background.

Found [this FAQ](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/faq#q-my-application-looks-different-in-all-platforms-why-is-that)...my scenario is just the opposite...it is NOT theme-ing to match the android vs iOS platorm! Why is it not dynamically being themed to match the simulator mode it is in (Android vs iOS)?

```
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the kendo.mobile.Application init in app.js - probably the flat skin is explicitly set. Just comment/remove the skin: "flat" line.